# I'm trying to filter products according to their categories on my laravel 8 app

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a marketplace and trying to filter products according to their categories, but the products do not appear.

**Filtering div**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10 mb-5 text-center">

              <ul class="product-category">
                    <li><a href="{{url('/shop')}}" class="active">All</a></li>
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <li><a href="{{url('/select_by_cat/'.$category->nom_categorie)}}">{{$category->nom_categorie}}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**Here is the div supposed to render the products**

```
<div class="row">
            @foreach ($products as $product)
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 ftco-animate">
              <div class="product">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{url('/storage/product_images/'.$product->prod_image)}}" alt="">
                    {{-- <span class="status">30%</span> --}}
                    {{-- <div class="overlay">Shop name and pic</div> --}}
                <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
                    <h3><a href="#">{{$product->prod_name}}</a></h3>
                    {{-- <h3><a href="#">{{$product->category_id->nom_categorie}}</a></h3> --}}
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p class="price"><span class="price-sale">{{$product->prod_price}}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-area d-flex px-3">
                        <div class="m-auto d-flex">
                            <a href="#" class="add-to-cart d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
                                <span><i class="ion-ios-menu"></i></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="buy-now d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mx-1">
                                <span><i class="ion-ios-cart"></i></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="heart d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                                <span><i class="ion-ios-heart"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function select_by_cat($nom_categorie)
{
    $products = Product::All()->where('category_id', $nom_categorie)->where('status', 1);

    $categories = Category::All();
    return view('client.shop')->with('products', $products)->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/select_by_cat/{nom_categorie}', [ProductController::class, 'select_by_cat']);
```

**Product model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        "prod_name",
        "prod_price",
        "prod_qty",
        "category_id",
        "prod_image",
        "status",
    ];


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Please include your Product model.

Comment: @KarlHill here it is 

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        "prod_name",
        "prod_price",
        "prod_qty",
        "category_id",
        "prod_image",
        "status",
    ];


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

Comment: Update your Product model to the answer I provided.

Comment: `Product::All()->where()` - You should almost _never_ do this... `::all()` will load **every record from your database table** into PHP's memory, then `->where()` will filter it. If you have ton of Records, you'll probably run out of memory. Correct syntax is `Product::where()->get()`; this will use your SQL database to do the filtering, then return only the required records, which has much better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have a relationship set up between the Product and Category models.

**Product Model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Next, you can modify your `select_by_cat()` method to use the relationship and the actual category id.

```
public function select_by_cat($nom_categorie)
{
    $category = Category::where('nom_categorie', $nom_categorie)->first();

    if (!$category) {
        abort(404); // You might want to handle this better
    }

    // Retrieve products with the specified category id and status
    $products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('status', 1)->get();

    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('client.shop')->with('products', $products)
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```